# SVN: any easy way to move a series of revisions+history for a file to be appended to another file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Obscure question for the SVN experts.

Imagine two files, A and B with revision history: Ar1 Br1, Ar2 Br2, Ar3 Br3. At that point of r3, I want to take the whole history of B and append it to A. In other words, it was discovered that B was a file that was based on A and the revisions historically happened after A3. So, I want the SVN repo to end up with this sequence:
Rev 1: Ar1, 
Rev 2: Ar2, 
Rev 3: Ar3,
Rev 4: Ar4 (from Br1), 
Rev 5: Ar5 (from Br2),
Rev 6: Ar6 (from Br3)

I know I can do this manually (copy each Revision of B into a working copy replacing A, commit & repeat), but I was wondering if there was any easy way to pick up the sequence and just append it to another sequence.

Thanks.

---

### Update: added SVN log of relevant history

---

r18 | buchs | 2012-02-17 12:00:34 -0600 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Project_Charter_B.docx

---

r12 | buchs | 2012-02-17 11:50:46 -0600 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Project_Charter_B.docx

---

r11 | buchs | 2012-02-17 11:47:15 -0600 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Project_Charter_B.docx

---

r9 | buchs | 2012-02-17 11:41:11 -0600 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Project_Charter_A.docx

---

r8 | buchs | 2012-02-17 11:39:02 -0600 (Fri, 17 Feb 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Project_Charter_A.docx

Comment: Why you want to rewrite history? For which task?

Comment: BTW, if you'll show `svn log` it will be alot better to understand

Comment: I am trying to capture history that was created outside of SVN by committing a series of changes. I thought two files were independent, but the one is a derivative of the other. Log shown above as requested.

Comment: Kevin - if log of B doesn't show copy a->b, you haven't "relation"  in repo history, and changing of commit-order doesn't change it

Comment: You are correctly identifying the problem. The SVN repo does not correctly reflect actual history. I want to change the SVN history to match. I do not really care about the actual dates for the commits, but just that the file history is captured.

Comment: Well, it's not a ready to use solution, but more [hint-list](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-06/0052.shtml) - tricky game, beware! You have to find, where (revision N) Project_Charter_B.docx appeared first time and insert one revision before this (appended revision must contain copy operation Project_Charter_A.docx -> Project_Charter_B.docx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see in log for /trunk/Project_Charter_B.docx such data as here *"...(from..."*, you have **big headache** to restore relation

```
svn log http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/i18n/Goededag.txt -v

r23 | lazybadger | 2010-07-17 06:05:00 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/i18n/Beaujour.txt (from /branches/i18n/Hello.fr.txt:22)
   A /branches/i18n/GuterTag.txt (from /branches/i18n/Hello.de.txt:20)
   D /branches/i18n/Hello.de.txt
   D /branches/i18n/Hello.en.txt
   D /branches/i18n/Hello.fr.txt
   A /branches/i18n/Hello.txt (from /branches/i18n/Hello.en.txt:20)
```